# Sorting one2manyfield openerpview

Tags: python, sorting, view, odoo

when you got the warehouse module installed in OpenERP 7
and open it at "incomming shipments" the products are sorted on the "id" in the database.
however I want to sort them on the product id.

Could someone explain me how to achieve this?

What I've got:

```
import logging
from osv import fields, osv
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class sortsupplies(osv.osv):
    _name = "stock.picking.in"
    _inherit = "stock.picking.in"
    _order = 'move_lines.product_id asc'
sortsupplies()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you showed should work. That's the right way of doing it.

Please take in account the following details. I suppose you put your code in a new module, let say `sortsupplies`.

First, to be able to inherit from `stock.picking.in` you have to include the module `stock` in your module's dependencies. This is done in your `__openerp__.py` file:

```
{
...
'depends': [..., 'stock'],
...
}
```

Second, to put your customization in action you have to **install your new module**, for example through the OpenERP's administration interface.

Comment: After a check i saw I already had stock in my dependencies. so unfortunately this isn't the problem

Comment: You want to sort what? The Incoming Shipments in the tree view or the Stock Moves inside a shipment?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it will work. An incoming shipment may have so many product moves. The same product move list can come under so many incoming shipments. So I think you better add a functional field with store condition, which calculates the integer depending on your condition. Then _order with this integer field